# How to update properties of nodes while merging in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-graphql-js

I want to merge my contacts with existing available contact nodes, but there is a minor issue I am facing.

I want to replace the name only if the name property does not exist
if exist I do not want to touch it let it be as it is
if the property is a null id empty string then I want to replace it with a new name property

any idea how it can be done in cypher  I am giving an example code below which I was trying with my best understanding

```
MATCH (me:User {id: $id})
      UNWIND $contacts AS c
      FOREACH (contact in c |
      MERGE (knows:User {number:contact.number}) 
      MERGE (me)-[:KNOWS]->(knows)
       SET
        knows.name = coalesce(knows.name, contact.name),
        knows.email = coalesce(knows.email, contact.email),
        knows.id =  coalesce(knows.id, contact.id),
        knows.anonymous = coalesce(knows.anonymous, randomUUID()),
      )
     RETURN knows

     const session = MyDriver.session();
    const result = await session.run(cypher, { id, contacts: myConctacts });
    session.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use coalesce where you provide a value in case the property doesn't exist, for eg :

```
SET knows.name = coalesce(knows.name, contact.name)
```

Reference : https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-coalesce

Comment: is this a good way to batch merge? or you can suggest a better way

Comment: @Rizwan wdym by batch merge ? The unwind + foreach ?

Comment: I mean batch insert  (i want to insert 30 contacts insert per second in  batch and make sure that no duplicate nodes with a merge that is called batch merge)

Comment: i have updated the question you can see I am trying to insert 30 nodes in my session and making sure no duplicates nodes

Comment: @Rizwan it's the good approach, check this https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-write-fast-furious/